# C# - System.Diagnostics.Process does not exist

Tags: c#, windows, universal, cortana

Literally just picked this up from scratch tonight, so bear with me.

I'm having a go at coding some Cortana commands, such as to shut down my computer (for example). I'm following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Wcn-ZK9mi4) through a Stack Overflow question I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431688/how-to-connect-cortana-commands-to-custom-scripts).

Everything works great - cortana picks up my command and runs the command as the tutorial states (display a pop up when the command is recognised).

However when I come to actually coding the shutdown command, `System.Diagnostics.Process`, it is not recognised. I have included the relevant `using` statements as well.

I've searched around and found (I think) that `Process` can no longer be used? Is this the case?

On another note, is there another way I can shutdown my machine from a C# Universal Windows App?:)

Comment: The author of the video was asked about how to actually turn off the computer in the comments. He realized he didn't really know how to do it and posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925096/how-to-execute-process-commands-or-similar-using-a-universal-windows-platform). It looks like its probably not possible. I'm tempted to just close this as a dupe of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is anyway to shutdown the OS from a UWP app.  They have removed any APIs from UWP which would have allowed this.

Comment: Would it be possible to call a batch file instead?

Comment: I believe they removed that too.

Comment: Yeah, its a give and take.  They could potentially add a new capability for this purpose.  You should submit it as an idea.  https://wpdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: I'm going to mark this as accepted as it looks like the API's have been removed, looking online.